# android how do i find out which view was clicked in a listview

Tags: java, android, android-listview, android-adapter

im quite a newby to android and java. I created a my own adapter and listView and i want to know how do i find out which view or row was pressed in my listView so i can do a specific task for row was picked (task includes sending data and info to another activity).

I thought that maybe the position variable contains the name of the row clicked so i tried it but when a row is clicked the app crashes

```
        hangarList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), position,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);

        }
    });
```

can someone help

Comment: post your log cat please.. showing the error message.

Comment: Set onitemclicklistener on yur listview.

Answer (score 0):

it could be that position is an integer, and it's expecting a string, and also the show() needs to be called on your toast to see the message.

```
 hangarList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), position+"",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you're on the right track regarding finding out which row was clicked.

The error lays in your use of `Toast.makeText()`. There are two versions of that method:

1. `makeText(Context context, int resId, int duration)`
2. `makeText(Context context, CharSequence text, int duration)`

Now in your vode you do `Toast.makeText(..., position, ...)` which invokes the first version of the method (as `position` is an integer), but because `position` is not a resource id the app crashes.

So, you have to use the second version and to do that, pass a `CharSequence` (or String) as second parameter: `Toast.makeText(..., position+"", ...)`

Btw. to get the actual value of the row, you can use `hangarList.getItemAtPosition(position)`.

Answer (score 0):

The views that make up the rows in the `ListView` are indexed like an array. The position value is the index of the row or view that was pressed. You can use the position value to look up the information associated with the clicked view.

Your app is crashing because `Toast.makeText(Context, int, int)` expects a string resource id integer for its second argument. When you give it the position as the id, it can't find that string resource and throws an exception. To display the index of the view that was clicked try:

```
hangarList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
                       "View at position " + position + " clicked.",
                       Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Application crashes because of your Toast.You should use Toast like

```
Toast.makeText(context, text, duration).show();
```

And you can fix it in simple way just like this:

```
String positionString=Integer.toString(position);
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), positionString,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

And there is no problem without Toast.As you say which item of listview is clicked?
For controlling which item is clicked You can use position variable of method.
Regards.. Omer